# How to default a column value from another table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Imagine I have two tables named Account and AccountStatus. In the Account table I got my account data including the accountStatusID by a Foreign Key referencing AccountStatus Primary Key.

In the AccountStatus table I insert all my possible user status (E.g. Account Non-Activated, Account Activated, Account Banned, etc).

Now my problem is when I insert an Account, I want my default value from AccountStatus to be "Account Non-Activated" which have some ID. I can't figure out how I can make this happen without hardcoding, like an Insert Trigger getting Select ID From AccountStatus WHERE AccountStatusTitle = "Account Non-Activated" and set the field (accountStatusID) from Account table.

Comment: Use a default constraint?

Comment: Does the ID for Account Non-Activated ever change? I would think that setting the default to 1 or whatever is not really a big deal unless the ID changes a lot which seems like probably a bad idea.

Comment: So hardcoding the ID really the best option here?

Comment: you can not have default value from other table. the only way is hard-coding or using trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option here would be to hard-code the ID using a default constraint.  If however you really want to avoid this then I would recommend the following:

a) Add an 'IsDefault' column to your AccountStatus table

b) Add a default constraint to the AccountStatusId field on the Account Table which calls a function which will return the id of the AccountStatus where the IsDefault column is set to true.

Hope this helps.